# Routing / in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm writing a simple Rails app with one main controller and I want to map `/(:action(:id))` to this controller (basically remove the controller prefix at the beginning), but still have the path helpers I get by using map.resources.

I tried `map.root :controller => 'notes'`, but I get an error:

> undefined method `note_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x102038b50>

where I use the `link_to_unless_current` function in my view.

Edit:  Here is the code in index.html.erb that gives the error.

```
<% for note in category.notes %>
    <h3><%= link_to_unless_current h(numbered_title note), note %></h3>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Need a little bit more information. Like post the actual code in the page with the link_to_unless_current and does going to the root work when you go there? Also I think you need a default action, I don't think you can say just map to a controller; how would it know what to draw?

Comment: `map.root :controller => 'notes', :action => 'index'` also doesn't work.

Comment: Besides, I would like to map not just `/` but `/:id`, `/:id/edit`, etc. as well.

Comment: Well, #note_path would be defined if you had a named route for notes... Do you actually have map.resources :notes in your route.rb file? Can you show us your complete routes.rb?

Comment: I just realized that you are using `map` which is old way of defining routes. Are you on rails 2.3?

Comment: @Lucas this question is three years old...

Comment: oh O_o I must have been sleeping -_-

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I don't know how I came to this question, but author just pointed out that this is 3 years old, which I totally missed. I will leave this answer if somebody needs that behaviour in rails 3. In rails 2 it is not valid...

Route `root` will not work with whole controller as this has to point on specific action.

First parameter of `resources` will be used to determine path (normally it would be `/notes`) and at the same time to create helpers like `notes_path`. What you want to do is set this to `'/'`, but also add `:as` option to give proper helpers names. So finally it should look like:

```
resources '/', controller: :notes, as: :notes
```

Also quite important thing to notice, if you want to use any other resources, you should put them above `notes` route. Otherwise rails will recognize resources name as `id` of notes action show.

Example:

```
resources '/', controller: :notes, as: :notes
resources :comments
```

Going to `/comments` will try to find note with id 'comments'.

```
resources :comments
resources '/', controller: :notes, as: :notes
```

Opening `/comments` will go to `comments_controller#index`.